# Table not appearing, but document compiles without errors

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx, texshop, sidewaystable

I'm writing up some tables for supplementary information and I've come across an issue. For context, I am using TexShop on a M1max MacBook Pro (i.e. running latest ARM version of TexShop).

In order to save space, I've combined two tables into one by making it very wide, as opposed to long (so it doesn't go over the page). However, when I tested whether it would fit (I compiled it in a separate document), the compilation finished without errors, but no image appeared on the display (I'll post a screenshot below). As part of the test, I added a couple of random letters at the beginning of the document, before the table, to see if the table was at fault. Again, nothing appeared on the display.

[image: Display screen with no output]

However, when I opened the PDF that TexShop created in Preview, a single page with the random letters appeared (without the table).

[image: PDF opened in Preview]

I honestly have no idea what the cause is, or even where to start looking for the issue. Even in creating the MWE (see below), I hoped gradually removing packages and recompiling would make the table appear... no such luck, unfortunately.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{report}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=4cm,right=2cm]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Maths
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%SI Units
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true, separate-uncertainty-units = single, retain-explicit-plus = true]{siunitx}

% Chemistry packages
\usepackage[layout=staggered-flat, arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}

% Table settings
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
\newcommand{\mr}{\multirow}

\begin{document}
hbk

\begin{sidewaystable}[H]
    \caption{Frequencies and intensities}
    \sisetup{table-alignment-mode = marker}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l l S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1] S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1] S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1] S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1]}
        \toprule
        \mc{2}{c}{\mr{3}{*}{\textbf{Assignment}}}   &   \mc{4}{c}{\textbf{B3LYP-D3/AVQZ}}   &   \mc{4}{c}{\textbf{DSD-PBEP86-D3(BJ)/AVDZ}}  \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-6}  \cmidrule(lr){7-10}
            &       &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{Harmonic}}    &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{GVPT2}}   &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{Harmonic}}    &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{GVPT2}}   \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-6}  \cmidrule(lr){7-8}  \cmidrule(lr){9-10}
            &       &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   \\
        \midrule
        \mr{6}{*}{\ce{^1H3P}} & \ce{\nu_{3s}} & 2414.5 & 40.1 & 2288.5 & 47.2 & 2458.2 & 41.5 & 2388.6 & 29.5 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{3a}} & 2412.1 & 43.1 & 2320.8 & 37.6 & 2455.6 & 44.0 & 2364.8 & 36.4 \\
            & \ce{\nu1} & 2403.5 & 34.6 & 2326.5 & 29.6 & 2440.3 & 32.9 & 2325.5 & 44.2 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{4s}} & 1136.1 & 10.0 & 1114.7 & 6.6 & 1142.9 & 9.9 & 1120.5 & 7.8 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{4a}} & 1136.4 & 11.4 & 1105.4 & 6.8 & 1142.8 & 11.2 & 1123.3 & 7.5 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{2}} & 1012.8 & 36.7 & 1006.8 & 25.4 & 1010.4 & 32.2 & 996.3 & 21.3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

If anyone can figure out what I might have done wrong, I would really appreciate it! As I said, I can't even begin to imagine what I've done wrong, considering no error messages popped up..

Comment: `rotating` does not support `[H]` for `sidewaystable`. After removing the option, the table would be shown at page 2. If you want to combine a table with not rotated text on the same page, you could use `\rotatebox` (and `\captionof`).

Comment: You are absolutely right! (Although it's still not appearing in TexShop's preview, for some reason...) If you add that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `[H]` is not supported by `rotating`. Just removing the option, would result in printing the table at page 2:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{report}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=4cm,right=2cm]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Maths
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%SI Units
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true, separate-uncertainty-units = single, retain-explicit-plus = true]{siunitx}

% Chemistry packages
\usepackage[layout=staggered-flat, arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}

% Table settings
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
\newcommand{\mr}{\multirow}

\begin{document}
hbk

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{Frequencies and intensities}
    \sisetup{table-alignment-mode = marker}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l l S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1] S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1] S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1] S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1]}
        \toprule
        \mc{2}{c}{\mr{3}{*}{\textbf{Assignment}}}   &   \mc{4}{c}{\textbf{B3LYP-D3/AVQZ}}   &   \mc{4}{c}{\textbf{DSD-PBEP86-D3(BJ)/AVDZ}}  \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-6}  \cmidrule(lr){7-10}
            &       &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{Harmonic}}    &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{GVPT2}}   &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{Harmonic}}    &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{GVPT2}}   \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-6}  \cmidrule(lr){7-8}  \cmidrule(lr){9-10}
            &       &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   \\
        \midrule
        \mr{6}{*}{\ce{^1H3P}} & \ce{\nu_{3s}} & 2414.5 & 40.1 & 2288.5 & 47.2 & 2458.2 & 41.5 & 2388.6 & 29.5 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{3a}} & 2412.1 & 43.1 & 2320.8 & 37.6 & 2455.6 & 44.0 & 2364.8 & 36.4 \\
            & \ce{\nu1} & 2403.5 & 34.6 & 2326.5 & 29.6 & 2440.3 & 32.9 & 2325.5 & 44.2 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{4s}} & 1136.1 & 10.0 & 1114.7 & 6.6 & 1142.9 & 9.9 & 1120.5 & 7.8 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{4a}} & 1136.4 & 11.4 & 1105.4 & 6.8 & 1142.8 & 11.2 & 1123.3 & 7.5 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{2}} & 1012.8 & 36.7 & 1006.8 & 25.4 & 1010.4 & 32.2 & 996.3 & 21.3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: sidewaystable without option H]

If you really want to combine the sideways table with not rotated text on the same page, you could use `\captionof` and `\rotatebox`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{report}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=4cm,right=2cm]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Maths
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%SI Units
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true, separate-uncertainty-units = single, retain-explicit-plus = true]{siunitx}

% Chemistry packages
\usepackage[layout=staggered-flat, arrows=pgf-filled]{mhchem}

% Table settings
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}
\newcommand{\mr}{\multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
hbk
\begin{center}
\rotatebox{90}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textheight-2\baselineskip}
    \captionof{table}{Frequencies and intensities}
    \sisetup{table-alignment-mode = marker}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l l S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1] S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1] S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1] S[table-format = 4.1] S[table-format = 3.1]}
        \toprule
        \mc{2}{c}{\mr{3}{*}{\textbf{Assignment}}}   &   \mc{4}{c}{\textbf{B3LYP-D3/AVQZ}}   &   \mc{4}{c}{\textbf{DSD-PBEP86-D3(BJ)/AVDZ}}  \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-6}  \cmidrule(lr){7-10}
            &       &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{Harmonic}}    &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{GVPT2}}   &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{Harmonic}}    &   \mc{2}{c}{\textbf{GVPT2}}   \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-6}  \cmidrule(lr){7-8}  \cmidrule(lr){9-10}
            &       &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Wavenumber}}  &   \mc{1}{Y}{\textbf{Intensity}}   \\
        \midrule
        \mr{6}{*}{\ce{^1H3P}} & \ce{\nu_{3s}} & 2414.5 & 40.1 & 2288.5 & 47.2 & 2458.2 & 41.5 & 2388.6 & 29.5 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{3a}} & 2412.1 & 43.1 & 2320.8 & 37.6 & 2455.6 & 44.0 & 2364.8 & 36.4 \\
            & \ce{\nu1} & 2403.5 & 34.6 & 2326.5 & 29.6 & 2440.3 & 32.9 & 2325.5 & 44.2 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{4s}} & 1136.1 & 10.0 & 1114.7 & 6.6 & 1142.9 & 9.9 & 1120.5 & 7.8 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{4a}} & 1136.4 & 11.4 & 1105.4 & 6.8 & 1142.8 & 11.2 & 1123.3 & 7.5 \\
            & \ce{\nu_{2}} & 1012.8 & 36.7 & 1006.8 & 25.4 & 1010.4 & 32.2 & 996.3 & 21.3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: using \rotatebox]

BTW: Without package `caption` using `\caption` above a table usually results in wrong formatting (to low distance between caption and table). So you should also use package `caption` in the first example.

Comment: For some reason, the caption looks fine for me without the caption package. Perhaps that's because the rest of the document is double-spaced?

Comment: @isolatedmatrix In the given example the distance is too small. BTW: You should also compare it with the caption distance of captions below figures. They should be similar.

Comment: I know, that's what I meant: my caption isn't as close to the `toprule` as yours, although I'm not sure why... maybe it's just an interaction between one of the packages I didn't include in the MWE? Either way, just thought I'd let you know